# Javascript for onblur event

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webmatrix, onblur

Building a registration form using webmatrix,asp.net & Javascript,sql server CE. I'm writing an onblur event for the Username textbox.When focus leaves the textbox, it checks if there is an exisiting username in database and displays a label if yes.The foll. code is not working as js code is ignored if inside the "@{}" block. It works fine outside the "@{}" block but then i cant give a condition there.Please help me out.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function RegUsernameLeave()
{
  @{
     regusername=Request.Form["regusername"];
     if(!regusername.IsEmpty())
      {
        var db = Database.Open("myshop");
        int usercount = db.QueryValue("select count(*) from webusers where username=@0",regusername);
        db.Close();
        if(usercount!=0){
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML="Username already exists";}
      }
   }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<label>Username:</label>
<p><input type="text" id="regusername" onblur="RegUsernameLeave()"/>
<label id="msg"></label></p>
</body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a complete stab in the dark here.. but maybe something along these lines?

Basically - I'm assuming that anything @{} is printed out into the JS - so if we can executed the server side code and output it equal to your JS variable userCount then you can use that JS Variable to do your checking and output the error message (if necessary)

```
@functions{ 
   public int GetUserCount() {
     string regusername = Request.Form["regusername"].ToString();
     if(!regusername.IsEmpty())
      {
        var db = Database.Open("myshop");
        int usercount = db.QueryValue("select count(*) from webusers where username='@0'",regusername);
        db.Close();
        return usercount;
      }
      return 0;
   }
}

function RegUsernameLeave()
{
    var userCount = @GetUserCount();

   if (userCount > 0)
   document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML="Username already exists";

}
```

Comment: Thank you Loren.Great Idea. But it errored out at "return usercount;" saying:"Since 'ASP._Page_test_cshtml.Execute()' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression."

Comment: Hey buddy, I made some revisions, I believe I'm getting closer

Comment: Yes.I think you are. But no luck:( It wasnt recognisisng 'regusername' so i added 'var'-"var regusername=Request.Form["regusername"];".So, no errors now but the warning didnt show up. So, i thought maybe the tab key press was not triggering onblur. I confirmed this with
"var userCount=1;if(userCount>0){do this.....}.It worked well. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I just revised the code - please check the updates, you were right I should have declared regusername - i made it string - also, I revised the sql statement some adding single quotes around the username value - can you try with these changes? - I also added a ; after the var userCount = @GetUserCount() assignment

Comment: T'was quick.Gave an error,but dont bother. Plz see, what i found:"@functions{ .......
           db.Close();
        return 22;
      }
      return 33;    
   }
}

function RegUsernameLeave()
{
   var userCount=@GetUserCount();
            alert(userCount);
}"..With/without text in the txtbox, it gives 33,meaning,the txt is not getting stored in regusername.Thats why it always shows 33.Does'Request.Form' only work with (Ispost).Cos, im using the same textbox and similar sql to store usrname in DB after btn click n it works.Hope this gives u some idea.